Why do my borders appear with extra borders when zooming or on devices like the iPad Air?
I'm facing an issue where my borders seem to have extra borders or a kind of double border effect when I zoom in on the page or when viewing it on different screen formats, like the iPad Air.
Here is the code for my component (React + Next.js + Tailwind CSS):
  return (
    <div className="space-y-8 sm:space-y-12 py-6 sm:py-12 mb-12 lg:mb-0">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-end relative">
        <FadeText
          text="Catégories"
          direction="right"
          className="text-4xl md:text-6xl lg:text-8xl font-extrabold tracking-tight"
        />
        <Link
          href="/produits/tous_les_produits"
          className="-mt-10 md:-mt-8 lg:-mt-10 text-sm font-semibold text-slate-800 hover:text-slate-600/80"
        >
          Voir tous les produits &rarr;
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div className="w-full relative">
        <div className="absolute inset-0">
          <Image
            src="/bac-a-pates.webp"
            alt="catégories"
            fill
            sizes="100vw"
            className="object-cover border-none"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="relative z-10 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 auto-rows-fr gap-0">
          {categories.map((item, index) => (
            <Link
              href={item.link}
              className={`w-full ${
                index === 0
                  ? "md:col-span-2 md:row-span-2"
                  : index === 1
                    ? "md:row-span-2"
                    : item.title === "Stockage des pâtes & ingrédients"
                      ? "md:row-span-2"
                      : ""
              }`}
              key={index}
            >
              <div className="relative bg-black bg-opacity-30 w-full h-full min-h-[200px] transition-all duration-300 hover:bg-opacity-50 border-4 lg:border-2 border-[#fffdf3]">
                <p className="text-white text-xl sm:text-2xl md:text-3xl p-3 font-bold absolute inset-0 flex items-end justify-start uppercase">
                  {item.title}
                </p>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );


Problem:
The borders (defined with border-4 and lg:border-2) appear with extra borders or double borders when:
I zoom in on the page.
I view the page on specific formats, such as the iPad Air.
This behavior isn't consistent and I can't figure out what's causing it.
Has anyone else experienced this issue and knows how to fix it?
Thanks for your help!
I have tried several things, such as setting border-style: none, using bg-clip-padding, and adjusting the border settings, but nothing seems to work.
Exemple

Could you create a CodeSandbox example or another resource to help us investigate the issue?

Here is the sandbox; you will see the problem when zooming between the categories. Don't hesitate to enlarge the preview; the components are responsive.
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/c26qf2

If you try to resize your page as a dev option in browsers inspect views its normal to show borders, in build version it won't appear if it's only appears that way if not so let me know.
Edit: Did you mean the way it acts when you use map and border together?
If you want that only certain cards have border you should put condition on which indexes have border-t or border-b or whatever border you want to add on it.
It's something like this:
{ index === 1 && ( <div className="relative bg-black bg-opacity-30 w-full h-full min-h-[200px] transition-all duration-300 hover:bg-opacity-50 border-4 lg:border-2 border-[#fffdf3]">
            <p className="text-white text-xl sm:text-2xl md:text-3xl p-3 font-bold absolute inset-0 flex items-end justify-start uppercase">
              {item.title}
            </p>
          </div> )} 
{ index !== 1 && ( <div className="relative bg-black bg-opacity-30 w-full h-full min-h-[200px] transition-all duration-300 hover:bg-opacity-50 border-b-4 border-x-4 lg:border-b-2 lg:border-x-2 border-[#fffdf3]">
            <p className="text-white text-xl sm:text-2xl md:text-3xl p-3 font-bold absolute inset-0 flex items-end justify-start uppercase">
              {item.title}
            </p>
          </div> )}

this is just sample you should edit it to match what you want.

it appear on build version..
